# SQL Laravel Eloquent - Where field can be uppercase or lowercase

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

`$pname` can be "`Airbus`", "`airbus`" or "`AIRBUS`"

```
$info = Plane::where('plane_name', '=', $pname)
                    ->where('uid', '=', $uid)
                    ->get();
```

Is there any way I can update this query to check the database for the plane name without case sensitivity?

Comment: It doesn't take case-sensitivity into consideration if you're using unicode_ci in MySQL configuration. It will be the case -sensitive if you use unicode_bin

Comment: or if you can't change your collation, and your data are always lowercase then compare them with lowercased input. strtolower($pname)

Comment: In MySQL I've actually found it harder to compare WITH case sensitivity than without because case sensitive collations are uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LOWER` MYsql function and `strtolower` php function

```
$info = Plane::whereRaw('LOWER(plane_name) = (?)', [strtolower($pname)])
                    ->where('uid', '=', $uid)
                    ->get();
```

**OR**

```
Plane::where('plane_name', 'ilike', $pname)->where('uid', '=', $uid)
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

just make sure result where clause to lowercase and query clause to lowercase too.

```
where(DB::raw('lower(column_name)'), '=', Str::lower($query))
```

dont forget to use:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add -> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; in Controller file.

**-----------Example---------------**

UserInfo::where(DB::raw('**upper**(username)'),  **strtoupper**($Request->username))

It's work for me, hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my issue, I have to do that on my Model.
simple copy and paste this function

```
public function __get($key)
    {

        if (is_null($this->getAttribute($key))) {
            return $this->getAttribute(strtoupper($key));
        } else {
            return $this->getAttribute($key);
        }

    }
```